# Actualizar listView cada 20 segundos

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un listView que cargo desde un servicio web. Funciona perfectamente, ahora quiero que se refresque solo cada 20 segundos y para ello he utilizado el siguiente código;

```
public class ListadoBC extends ActionBarActivity {

String ref = "";
String hora ="";
String op ="";
String equipo="";
int pulsado = -1;
int click = -1;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<BienCultural> listaBC = new ArrayList<BienCultural>();
ArrayList<Integer> bienes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_bc1);

    listado();
}


public void listado()
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Descargando listado ...");
    progressDialog.setTitle("Progreso");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    ListadoAsyncTask listadoAsyncTask = new ListadoAsyncTask();
    listadoAsyncTask.execute("http://swa.hol.es/conectar1.php");
}

public void actualizarDisplay()
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.bien_cultural, listaBC);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            listado();
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 20000); //now is every 2 minutes
        }
    }, 20000);
}
```

}

Listado guarda los datos del webService en un ArrayList que luego se lo paso al adapter

Se ha actualizado durante 1 minuto sin problema, pero de repente ha dado error y ha cerrado la app. 
El error del logcat es:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Alguna idea?

Comment: desde donde llamas actualizarDisplay() ??? podrías agregar tu clase completa?

Comment: @Jorgesys la clase es muy larga, pero te hago un esquema, en el create() llamo a un asynTask (a través de la función listado(), Ese asynTask, recoge los datos del servicio web y  en su método onPostExecute() llama a actualizar display (). Primero puse un boton y al llamar a listado actualizaba perfectamente. El caso es como hacerlo periódico.

Comment: que contiene el método  listado(); ?

Answer (score 1):

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Estas realizando una actualización de los datos en el `ListView` pero desde un Thread en background, primeramente asegura este proceso solo se llamé una sola ocasión:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listado();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 20000); 
    }
}, 20000);
```

y para solucionar el problema

> "El contenido del adaptador ha cambiado pero ListView no recibió una
>   notificación"

, asegura actualizar los datos mediante [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()):

```
 dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Jorgesys estaba leyendo justo ahora sobre eso en este [https://codigoscript.com/2015/04/16/como-actualizar-un-listview/] ¿cómo se asegura que el hilo se llame una unica vez? Como meto los datos actulizados en el adaptador sin setAdapter()? Es mi primera vez con listView

Comment: he puesto lo mas relevante de la clase por si ayuda

Comment: veo que el Asynctask crea el handler para actualizar, pero ese ASynctask esta creando varios procesos para actualziar cada 20 segundos! =|